# Get Rails current locale in ISO 15897 locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

I'd like to retrieve the current locale of my Rails application in ISO 15897 format.

Any way to format the current locale into this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you maintain a map internally of locales you actually support?

Something like this:

```
def locale_iso15897(locale)
  iso_map = {
    "en" => "en_US.UTF8",
    "fr" => "fr_FR.UTF8",
    "fr-CA" => "fr_CA.UTF8",
    "pl" => "pl_PL.UTF8"
  }
  iso_map[locale.to_s]
end
```